# Handling stream socket errors in UWP c++winRT

Tags: sockets, error-handling, c++-winrt

I've tried to adapt the microsoft example [streamsocket app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/streamsocket/).

I can pass information back and forth but can't handle network errors.

```
//.h
bool connected{ false };
bool closing { false };
Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocket m_streamSocket;
Windows::Networking::HostName hostName{ L"192.168.86.48" };
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction OpenSocket();

//.cpp
using namespace Windows::Networking::Sockets;

Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::OpenSocket() {

    if (connected) {
      return;
    }

    try
    {
        co_await m_streamSocket.ConnectAsync(hostName, L"1337");
        connected = true;
    }
    catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex)
    {
        OutputDebugStringW(L"catch");
        SocketErrorStatus errorStatus = SocketError::GetStatus(ex.to_abi());


        if (errorStatus == SocketErrorStatus::ConnectionTimedOut) 
        {
            connected = false;
            OutputDebugStringW(L"ConnectionTimedOut");
    }
        SocketErrorStatus webErrorStatus{ SocketError::GetStatus(ex.to_abi()) };
        auto msg = (webErrorStatus != SocketErrorStatus::Unknown) ? winrt::to_hstring((int32_t)webErrorStatus) :winrt::to_hstring(ex.to_abi());

    std::wstringstream str;
    str \<\< L"webErrorStatus: " \<\< msg;
    ::OutputDebugString(str.str().c_str());

        closing = true;
    //no dispose in c++winrt?
    m_streamSocket = nullptr;
    }

}
```

The connection works as expected when I open the host.  When I don't and allow the connection to time out the app crashes with:

`Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDBE624C3C (KernelBase.dll) in Monitor1.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x8007274C : 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.'.`

I can't catch the error before the crash.  In the above code the catch block never executes.  "catch" and "ConnectionTimedOut" never print to the output.  I can't find any c++winRT networking code samples online that handle errors.  I suspect the try..catch is not catching them somehow...

thanks everyone

Comment: Have you tried running the code without a debugger attached? You can see the `OutputDebugString` logs using a tool like [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview). Other than that, I believe what you have is how the system is intended to work: Asynchronous errors are translated to C++ exceptions, that get re-thrown on the thread that initiated the asynchronous operation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply: it doesn't make a difference.  It would be really helpful if microsoft had a working c++winrt networking sample with error handling included :-(

Comment: Can the exception be caught after replacing `catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex)`  `catch (Platform::Exception^ exception)` ? Get errorStatus `SocketErrorStatus errorStatus = SocketError::GetStatus(exception->HResult);`

Comment: Think that's c++/cx.  I'll ask the question on the microsoft forums and post back if I get any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Microsoft team solved the problem [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1368428/handling-stream-socket-errors-in-uwp-c-winrt).

The exception was actually being thrown by Visual Studio before it could be caught by the try..catch block.  The answer was to disable the exception alert in VS in the dialog box that came up.

Here's a copy of the working code:

```
//.xaml
<ListBox x:Name="clientListBox">

//.h
bool connected{ false };
bool closing { false };
Windows::Networking::Sockets::StreamSocket m_streamSocket;
hstring socketAddress = L"1337";
Windows::Networking::HostName hostName{ L"192.168.86.48" };
Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction OpenSocket();

//.cpp
using namespace Windows::Networking::Sockets;

Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MainPage::OpenSocket() {

    if (connected) {
        clientListBox().Items().Append(winrt::box_value(L"already connected"));
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        clientListBox().Items().Append(winrt::box_value(L"client is trying to connect..."));
        co_await m_streamSocket.ConnectAsync(hostName, socketAddress);
        connected = true;
        clientListBox().Items().Append(winrt::box_value(L"client connected"));
    }
    catch (winrt::hresult_error const& ex)
    { 
        SocketErrorStatus errorStatus = SocketError::GetStatus(ex.to_abi());
        connected = false;
        closing = true;
        //no dispose in c++winrt?
        m_streamSocket = nullptr;
    
        std::wstringstream wstringstream;
        //full list here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.socketerrorstatus            

        if (errorStatus == SocketErrorStatus::ConnectionTimedOut) {
            clientListBox().Items().Append(winrt::box_value(L"Computer at - " + hostName.RawName() + L": " + socketAddress + L" timed out.\nCheck it is trying to connect."));
            wstringstream << L"A connection attempt failed.";
            ::OutputDebugString(wstringstream.str().c_str());
        }

        else if (errorStatus == SocketErrorStatus::ConnectionRefused) {
            //WinRT originate error - 0x8007274D : 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.'.
            clientListBox().Items().Append(winrt::box_value(L"Other computer refused connection - \nCheck IP: " + hostName.RawName() + L"\nCheck socket: " + socketAddress));
            wstringstream << L"Connection actively refused.\n";
            ::OutputDebugString(wstringstream.str().c_str());
        }

        else {
            auto msg = (errorStatus != SocketErrorStatus::Unknown) ? winrt::to_hstring((int32_t)errorStatus) : winrt::to_hstring(ex.to_abi());
            wstringstream << L"webErrorStatus: " << msg;
            ::OutputDebugString(wstringstream.str().c_str());
        }
    }
}
```